# Passing the input values to procedure via shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, stored-procedures

I have the following user input code in shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter name"
read -r name
echo "Enter email Id"
read -r email
echo "Enter the gender
        choose among the following
        (1-Male
        2-Female
        3-Others)" = "$num"  
    read -r num

if [ "$num" = "1" ] 
then
echo "MALE"

elif [ "$num" = "2" ] 
then
echo "FEMALE"

elif [ "$num" = "3" ] 
then
 echo "OTHERS"

fi
echo "Do you nedd the pass book = $data_rep"
read -r data_rep
if [ "$data_rep" = "YES" ] 
then
echo "YES"
elif [ "$data_rep" = "NO" ]
then
echo "NO"
fi

 echo "You entered name as" "$name"
 echo "You entered Email Id as" "$email"
 echo "You chose gender  as" "$num"
 echo "You chose answer for passbook as" "$data_rep"
```

I want to add the above user input to a procedure
The procedure also has the same parameters.
How to pass the value of the user input to the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus $UID@$SID <<!
$PWD

exec procedure_name('$name','$email','$num');

!
```

Where UID - your username, SID - your Oracle tnsname, PWD - password